# inserting date gmt with datetime

Tags: php

How do I change this so the time is GMT the date comes up right but time is wrong.

Any help would be grateful,Thanks

```
function format_mysql_datetime($raw) {
    $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
    $stringtime =  strtotime($raw);
    return strftime($format, $stringtime);  
}

$raw = date('c');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Cars` VALUES ('', 'Pending', '$price', '{$fetchAccount['email']}', '$raw', '$content', '$description', '$area', '$town', '$UK', '$target', '0')") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the timezone

use this

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

Comment: @user1722740 use this at the top of page.

Comment: @user1722740 if this answer helped than you can accept the answer by clicking the `right` arrow bottom the voting pannel...

Comment: I did it another way but thanks couldn't get your way to work.

Comment: if you have solved the problem in another way, you should add that as an answer to your question, so that future visitors can see how you solved it